# Display DataFrame in Jupyter Notebook, Depending on a Condition

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

In a Jupyter Notebook, I am having a DataFrame named `tradelines_df`. And I want to display it **nicely**, depending on a condition. **Nicely** means like this:

[image]

I have tried:

```
condition = True
if condition:
    tradelines_df
```

but it is not displayed at all. I can write:

```
if condition:
    print(tradelines_df)
```

But it is not **nicely** displayed:
[image]

Any ideas here?

Comment: what exactly does it look like

Comment: you can try `display` - display(tradelines_df)

Comment: maybe add an image of that

Comment: Np - it would be helpful if you can accept the answer as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display`

```
if condition: 
    display(tradelines_df)
```

Answer (score 2):

just use `display`. Suppose this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"year": [2021, 2020, 2019]})
condition = True
```

Then print it if the `condition` is `true`:

```
if condition: 
    display(df)
```

[image]